# HP dv7t quad laptop hangs SOMETIMES when I put it into sleep mode (Win7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep

I recently purchased HP DV7tQE laptop (i7-2760QM CPU, 16GB RAM, 120 GB SSD + 750 HDD,  win7 x64). When I close the lid (or click Sleep in start menu), *sometimes* it would turn off the display but backlight on keyboard would be still on, harddrive would make sounds etc - and there is no way I can put back to live. If I wait long enough (5-10 minutes) - it would eventually shut itself off - but then when I start it, it loads windows and displays "Windows was not shut down properly" screen. All my work is lost.

As I said, it does not happen all the time. If I restart Windows and put it into sleep - then it will work. However, if I work for some time, it might go to sleep properly, but more often than not, it will hang.

Any ideas? what should I look at?..

Comment: Have you already updated to the latest available drivers? There should be a program named HP Update or similar which will enable the laptop to grab the latest from HP's support site and install it.

Comment: Are you using the Windows installation that came with the laptop, or are you using a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your power settings first. If Hybrid Sleep is enabled, turn it off.

Start > type: 'powercfg.cpl' in search box > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings > expand sleep > uncheck allow hybrid sleep and hit apply.